# Local JSON file is not parsing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large JSON file which has around 5000 entries and when I parse it using fetch(), it doesn't show up in browser.
Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Box.css';

class Box extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {movieName: []}
 }
 componentDidMount() {
  fetch('./MovieDatabaseShort.json')
  .then(a => a.json())
  .then(movieName => this.setState({movieName}));
 }
 renderMovies() {
  const { movieName } = this.state;
  return movieName.map(a => {
   <h1 key={ a.id } className='heading'>{a.title}</h1>;
  });
 }
 render() {
  return <div className="box">{this.renderMovies()}</div>;
 }
}
export default Box;
```

I just want to put all the movies titles.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Box.css';

class Box extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {movieName: []}
 }
 componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761627/example_1.json')
  .then(a => a.json())
  .then(movieName => this.setState({movieName: movieName.color}));
 }
 render() {
  console.log( this.state );
  return <div className="box">{this.state.movieName}</div>;
 }
}
export default Box;
```

**EDIT**- In second code, I just copied random json file from net and it works fine. I think its's due to size of the json file I have. It's 250k+ lines.

**Update**- This works. I think problem is due to `fetch()`

```
import React from 'react';
import './Box.css';
import a from './MovieDatabaseShort.json'
class Box extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {movieName: []}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({movieName: a});
    }
    renderBox() {
        const { movieName } = this.state;
        return movieName.map(k => {
            return <h1 className='heading'>{k.title}</h1>;
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='box'>{this.renderBox()}</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Box;`
```

Comment: Can we see a part of your json file?

Comment: Any errors in your console? Also did you check that the data is being returned from that fetch? I can get it to work here with some random api: https://jsfiddle.net/5vjqabv3/6446/

Comment: @justDan no errors in console and yes i also tried with some random json file from the web and it worked by not with my json file. I'll post a part of my json file(not whole 'cause its too big 100k+ lines).

Comment: here's my json file https://jsfiddle.net/de85mpky/

Comment: @devserkan check this json file.

Comment: If you use arrow function with a body block, with curly braces you have to return it explicitly. Put a return: `return <h1 key={ a.id } className='heading'>{a.title}</h1>;`

Comment: @devserkan still nothing happened.

Comment: That's really odd. Even if I use your array in another fiddle I can get a list to populate: https://jsfiddle.net/5vjqabv3/6470/. That's also not using the fetch call though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are some places you should change in your code.

- You should keep an array property in your state for all movies: `movies: []`
- You should map this state value, then render some JSX.
- Use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in a future release.

Here is the example code:

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { movies: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./MovieDatabaseShort.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(movies => this.setState({ movies }));
  }

  renderMovies() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return movies.map(movie => (
      <h1 key={movie.title} className="heading">
        {movie.title}
      </h1>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="box">{this.renderMovies()}</div>;
  }
}
```

If you still don't see anything maybe `fetch` would the problem here. Then, try this:

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { movies: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    import("./MovieDatabaseShort.json").then(movies =>
      this.setState({ movies })
    );
  }

  renderMovies() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return movies.map(movie => (
      <h1 key={movie.title} className="heading">
        {movie.title}
      </h1>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="box">{this.renderMovies()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Again, if nothing is shown up please share you JSON file with us as well as check your console if there is any error.

Comment: In both answers, the page is just showing empty outlined box(due to the css property attached with div). I'll post a part of my json file. and console shows no errors in both answers.

Comment: @ManishPant, I've seen the JSON. Can you update your question with your current code? Just add the current one, do not replace it. Also, can you try a console.log in your render method? Just below like: `render() {
 console.log( this.state );
    return <div className="box">{this.renderMovies()}</div>;`

Comment: i console loged it and it returned object with empty movieName array

Comment: i think it's due to size of the json file i have(250k+ lines). i tried using random json file from net and it works fine.

Comment: Can you share it somehow? You can try to import it directly. Put an import statement top of your file: `import movies from "./MovieDatabaseShort.json";` Then change your state like this: `this.state = { movies };` Then, remove `componentDidMount` block and try again.

Comment: I've tried this on the local with a JSON file which has 350K lines and it worked. It was slow, my browser stalled a little bit but it worked at the end. Due to its size maybe you need special JSON parsing methods on your side. Also, importing it directly, as I explained in the above comment, is faster. File size: 11M

Comment: Have you tried my second option in this answer? The one with `import` and without `fetch`? Because it works also for me. And, come on, at least give an upvote and consider accepting my answer for all my struggle here :)

Comment: Thank for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you want to do is to save all movies into an array on your state. That would look more like this:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {movies: []}
}
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('./MovieDatabaseShort.json')
    .then(a => a.json())
    .then(b => this.setState({movies: b}));
}
```

Then in your render function you would loop over your movies and display the title:

```
render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className='box'>
            {movies.map(movie => <h1 className='heading'>{movie.title}</h1>)}       
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use fetch() for a local file. You would need to serve that data from a url and then fetch it. Or you could just import that json into your component

Comment: also you probably want to do data fetching in componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

Another way using hook can be the following. In my case I need to take configuration data from a json file

```
import _data from '../../json/config.json';
export const Mapa = () => {
  
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{                 
          setConfig(_data );
          
    },[]);
}
```